# Is it better to implement strtol() without errno?

Tags: c, linux, string, strtol

Traditional `strtol()` is usually used like this:

```
int main()
{
    errno = 0;
    char *s = "12345678912345678900";
    char *endptr;
    long i = strtol(s,  &endptr, 10);
    if(i == LONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) 
        printf("overflow");
}
```

We need to access `errno` two times, and `errno` nowadays is usually a C macro finally expanded to a function.  It seems a little expensive considering parsing string to integer isn't a heavy job.

So, is it better to implement `strtol` without `errno` but using some other ways to indicating overflow?

like:

```
long strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base, bool *is_overflow);
```

instead of

```
long strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. You don't *implement* strtol, you use it. Are you asking whether you should reimplementing strtol such that it doesn't use errno?

Comment: I believe Posix requires `errno` so its not really feasible to do. Also, you will spend most of your time in the conversion algorithm. Conversion probably runs in ***`O(n)`***. Setting `errno` runs in ***`O(1)`***. Setting `errno` is mostly insignificant.

Comment: If there is no `errno`, how do you know if there was no overflow?

Comment: Correct me if I mistaken but you don't have to set `errno` to zero;  -since it is rvalue it would be ill-formed-.

Comment: @ShmuelH. It is an lvalue (a function returning a pointer, disguised as a variable.)

Comment: @user202729 thanks for reminding, I indeed want to implement my `strol` so I asked this question.  @DYZ thanks, I have edited the last line.

Comment: `enptr` should be `endptr`.

Comment: Related, here is libc's [`strtol.c` implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/strtol.c)

Comment: Uh, the default implementation is not that efficient. Have you taken a look at the [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/dm22Ab)? `__errno_location` is only called once.

Comment: @user202729 With the `-O2` option, the location of `errno` was calculated and cached. With `-O0`, `__errno_location` is called twice.

Comment: There is no reason to initialize `endptr`. When using `strtol`, you have 2 validations (1) `if (s == endptr && i = 0) { /* error no digits converted */ }` and then (2) `else if (errno) { /* over/underflow occurred */ }`. So, No it is not better to avoid using `errno`.

Comment: @weiweishuo If you care about performance you would not compile with -O0. Obviously.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Looks valid to post in an answer;; although the OP is concerned that the function call __errno_location (or equivalent) may be slow.

Comment: The performance concern is a strange concern, since at most it will be implemented as a macro setting a global based on a simple lookup. I would not expect it to be any performance concern whatsoever.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  have edited the code, thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why suggest `if (s == endptr && i = 0)` vs. just `if (s == endptr)`?

Comment: Simply because "that's what the man page says"? I've always thought `if (s == endptr)` was fine (and I'm sure it is), but the man page reads `if (s == endptr && i = 0)` so for completeness, I include it. (e.g. `"stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0)"`)

Comment: `errno` is not a good method of error reporting. If you are not bound by an existing interface, it's better to use some other method. Don't call yor function strtol, and use whatever method you want. But strtol is set in stone.

Comment: @weiweishuo - unless you are concerned with determining whether the return is `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX`, there is no 2nd comparison involving `errno` required. In either case `errno` is set and it is enough to check that `errno` is non-zero. Additionally, once `errno` is set, you incur no addition penalty in accessing its value (no more than accessing the value of any variable)

Comment: To implement your own variation of `strtol()` in C code is an unfair race for you. 
 You are pitted against `strtol()` which is implemented in C or assembly or whatever and is crafted to be fast on _that_ platform.

Comment: `errno` is guaranteed an lvalue, the actual implementation is completely irrelevant. If it is a macro calling a function and dereferencing the returned `int *`, the compiler might be able to optimise multiple calls. Leave such optimisations to the toolchain, unless you have reason to do otherwise. However, this is hardly ever the bottleneck. Don't do premature optimisations. **If** you have a performance problem, profile and optimise identified hotspots.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `errno` is in TLS, so there typically is a lookup in the symbol table if threads are supported. However, this is normally only done once in a function (or even larger scale) and hardly a problem in actual code - expecially in the context of string parsing.

Answer (score 4):

> is it better to implement strtol without errno ...

No.

> ... but using some other ways to indicating overflow?

No.

```
long int strtol(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);
```

`strtol()` is a standard C library function and any implementation must adhere to proper use of the 3 inputs and `errno` to be compliant.

---

Of course OP can implement some other `my_strtol()` as desired.

Any performance concerns around avoiding `errno` are  a micro-optimization yet a reasonable design goal.

It really comes down to how to conveys problems of *string* to `long`

- Overflow `"12345678912345678901234567890"`
- No conversions `"abc"`
- Excess junk `"123 abc"`
- Leading space allowed, trailing space allowed?
- Allow various bases?

Once functionality about all exceptional cases are defined, not just overflow, then coding concerns about `errno` is useful, even if unlikely to make any meaningful performance improvements.

IMO, coding to one base only is likely a more productive path to speed improvements than `errno`.

---

OP code is not a robust `strtol()` usage.  Suggest:

```
char *s = "12345678912345678900";

char *endptr;
errno = 0;
long i = strtol(s,  &endptr, 10);
if (errno == ERANGE) printf("Overflow %ld\n", i);
else if (s == endptr) printf("No conversion %ld\n", i);
else if (*endptr) printf("Extra Junk %ld\n", i);
else printf("Success %ld\n", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually some overhead besides `errno` in `strtol()`, like skipping spaces, taking care of the base (10 or hexa), check characters ...

In a **specific environment** where speed is critical and **you know the string provided is a number base 10** that fits in a `long`, you could make your own quick function, like

```
#include <ctype.h>

long mystrtol(char *s) {
   long res = 0, minus = *s == '-';
   if (minus || *s == '+') s++;

   while (isdigit(*s)) {
      res = res*10 + (*s++ - '0');
   }

   return minus ? -res : res;
}
```

and choose to inline it.

Comment: Nit, but `+10` is also a valid numeric representation that gets handled. The corner cases are what make the use of the standard library functions preferable over rolling your own.

Comment: Indeed  ;  I guess if speed is that critical and they know no useless `+` is prefixing the string... they could also replace `isdigit(*s)` with `*s`...

Comment: Yes, that wasn't to take away from your algorithm, it's fine, I guess the main point for the OP is unless you can exclude all corner cases and roll your own to fit one particular conversion, then it's just hard to beat the years of development and optimization already built into the library functions. Even then, years later somebody runs the code against a normal variation not covered and all hell breaks loose. Worrying about micro-optimization is at best Russian-Roulette.

Comment: Corner concerns: `isdigit(*s)` is technical UB when `*s < 0` (cast to `unsigned char`) .  Further `res = res*10 + (*s++ - '0');` is UB (signed integer overflow) when the target result is in range as `LONG_MIN`.  The _usual_ UB in these cases is OK, yet still UB.

Comment: In addition to issues already listed, the function should be const-correct, i.e. use `const`. Many reasonable coding standard require pointers to string literals declared that way (and it's good practice on most platforms). Also the premise is questionable at best. Standard library functions are often implemented highly efficient, up to optimised assembler code. Also the flexibility of the original might be a nice extra for the user (e.g. being able to use other bases).

Comment: @chux not *technical UB* but **grave UB of wholly unpredictable behaviours on any platforms that use signed chars** if a negative byte goes in...

Comment: The correct usage of `isdigit` is **only** as follows: `isdigit((unsigned char)*s)`.

Comment: Edited to underline (bold) in which conditions the function had to be used.